# How do I run private docker images on Google Container Engine

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

How do I run a docker image that I built locally on [Google Container Engine](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/)?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can push your image to [Google Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/tools/container-registry/) and reference them from your pod manifest.

### Detailed instructions

Assuming you have a `DOCKER_HOST` properly setup , a GKE cluster running the last version of Kubernetes and [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/) installed.

1. Setup some environment variables

   ```
   gcloud components update kubectl
   gcloud config set project <your-project>
   gcloud config set compute/zone <your-cluster-zone>
   gcloud config set container/cluster <your-cluster-name>
   gcloud container clusters get-credentials <your-cluster-name>
   ```
2. Tag your image

   ```
   docker tag <your-image> gcr.io/<your-project>/<your-image>
   ```
3. Push your image

   ```
   gcloud docker push gcr.io/<your-project>/<your-image>
   ```
4. Create a pod manifest for your container: `my-pod.yaml`

   ```
   id: my-pod
   kind: Pod
   apiVersion: v1
   desiredState:
     manifest:
       containers:
       - name: <container-name>
         image: gcr.io/<your-project>/<your-image>
       ...
   ```
5. Schedule this pod

   ```
   kubectl create -f my-pod.yaml
   ```
6. Repeat from step (4) for each pod you want to run. You can have multiple definitions in a single file using a line with `---` as delimiter.

Comment: on `gcloud preview container pods --cluster-name cluster-1 create --zone europe-west1-c --config-file registry-pod.yaml` there is a  
 `resource.go:132] The resource in the provided file has no apiVersion defined`

Comment: see https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/examples/gce-pd/testpd.yaml for updated pod example

Comment: Google Container Engine (GKE) has moved on to Kubernetes 0.6.1, so referring to localhost no longer works. The current workaround is to refer to your private repository by its IP. See also: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/wiki/User-FAQ

Comment: ^ you get the private ip from creating the registry service. ```gcloud preview container services list --cluster $CLUSTER --zone $ZONE``` and replacing 'localhost:5000/image' with '<registry-service-ip>:5000/image'

Comment: updated the answer to use [Google Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/tools/container-registry/)

Comment: when `gcr.io/<gcr_namespace>/<your-image>` is updated how do you update the running container?

Comment: @eloone you can just restart the pod if your image ends up with `:latest`, (the default `imagePullPolicy` is `PullAlways` if `:latest`).  See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/api/v1beta2/types.go#L199 and https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/images.md#preloading-images for more information about pull policy.

Comment: @eloone another way to ensure a pull is to always version your images. Since `imagePullPolicy` defaults to `PullIfNotPresent` if not `:latest`, when you update the pod image with a new version number suffix, it will pull this image if it's not present on the node.

Comment: is it possible to use an image from docker hub or it has to be uploaded on gcloud registry tagged as 'gcr.io/<image>'? I am probably missing something.

Answer (score 1):

The setup I use is to [deploy my own docker registry](http://ruediste.github.io/cloud/2017/02/23/docker-registry-on-gke.html) combined with ssh port forwarding. For that purpose I set up a ssh server in the cluster and use `~/.ssh/config` to configure a port forward to the registry.

Also I use jenkins to build the images right in the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Specify the container in which you have to work on

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials [$cluster_name]
```

Step 2: Tag the docker image you want to run

```
docker tag nginx gcr.io/first-project/nginx
```

Step 3: Push image

```
gcloud docker push gcr.io/first-project/nginx
```

Step4:Create yaml file (test.yaml)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
containers:
- name : nginx1
  image: gcr.io/first-project/nginx
```

Step 5 : Create the pod

```
kubectl create –f test.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the registry authentication key of your private docker registry to the .dockercfg file in the root directory of the minions right before starting the pods.
Or run docker login on minions before starting.

```
    docker login --username=<> --password=<> --email=<> <DockerServer>
```

Referring to the private docker image in the pod configuration should then work as expected.

Comment: Where can I find username and password for the Google Container Registry?

Comment: Is there any way to automate this in GKE? I tried running docker login on the nodes but I still get imagepulloff errors when starting the workload. Im using gitlab container registry which does allow you to log in with your password and/or tokens.