# How do I proxy docker registries in Google Container Engine (GKE)?

Tags: docker, google-kubernetes-engine

Similarly to the user in this question: [How do I run private docker images on Google Container Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788485/how-do-i-run-private-docker-images-on-google-container-engine):

- I'd like to non-dockerhub docker images in GKE.
- I would prefer to not have to explicitly prefix my images with a docker IP address.
- This is in a live cluster, so re-installing nodes isnt really a good idea.

Is there a way I can fire up new nodes in the cluster with a configuration that adds a new default search path for a registry to the docker daemons on the kubelets, or similar workaround.

Comment: I am not sure if registry mirrors in `docker daemon` config can be of help here, but you should give it a shot. `--registry-mirror list                  Preferred Docker registry mirror (default [])`

Comment: Yeah ,thats what i wanted, but not sure if I can do this, i.e. if arbitrary registry options are supported in GKE.

Comment: Okie, even i can't find much documentation on it and even see if it is possible or not